# Reducing memory usage?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a relatively simple task which is exposing an issue with efficiency. In that it isn't very efficient and the server cries and quits. Here's the high level overview:

There's a category called "Locations". There are 791 locations.
Users have three Category Fields; First Choice, Second Choice, Third Choice. The pick one location in each field. There are 1809 Users.

I need to generate a report that shows how popular each location is (how many Users chose [LOCATION] as their 1st, 2nd, and 3rd choice). A nice simple table that's 4 cells wide and 791 rows deep.

I keep running out of memory and execution time regardless of how high I take each limit. I've tried it in Twig and I've tried it in PHP as a plugin.

My strategy, via creating a Service and a Variable... :

```
{% set locations = craft.categories.group('locations').limit(null) %}
{% set users     = craft.users.group('members').limit(null) %}

{{ craft.reporting.locationPopularity(locations,users) }}
```

The ReportsService.php file:

```
public function locationPopularity($locations = null, $users = null) {
    $response = "";

    foreach($locations as $location) {
        $firstChoiceCount = 0;
        $secondChoiceCount = 0;
        $thirdChoiceCount = 0;

        foreach($users as $user) {
            if($user->firstChoiceLocation->last() == $location){ $firstChoiceCount += 1; }
            if($user->secondChoiceLocation->last() == $location){ $secondChoiceCount += 1; }
            if($user->thirdChoiceLocation->last() == $location){ $thirdChoiceCount += 1; }
        }

        $response = $response . "
            <h2>$location->title</h2>
            <p>First Choice: $firstChoiceCount, Second Choice: $secondChoiceCount, Third Choice: $thirdChoiceCount.</p>";
    }

    return $response;
}
```

How do I get this to work? 1,430,919 loop iterations seems to be a no go.

The following works, but 2400+ queries...

```
{% for location in craft.categories.group('locations').limit(null).find() %}
    {% set firstChoiceCount = craft.users.relatedTo({
        element: location,
        field: 'firstChoiceLocation'
    }).limit(null).count() %}

    {% set secondChoiceCount = craft.users.relatedTo({
        element: location,
        field: 'secondChoiceLocation'
    }).limit(null).count() %}

    {% set thirdChoiceCount = craft.users.relatedTo({
        element: location,
        field: 'thirdChoiceLocation'
    }).limit(null).count() %}

    ... output ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `->last()` will always produce 2 queries, one fetches the total amount of results, the other one fetches the result with the offset given by the first query -> you can reduce the amount of queries by using `first()` if there is only one choice.

Furthermore: I would make use of [eager loading](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/eager-loading-elements.html) so you don't even fetch the fields again and again (like currently)

```TWIG
{% set users = craft
    .users
    .group('members')
    .limit(null)
    .with([
        'firstChoiceLocation', 
        'secondChoiceLocation', 
        'thirdChoiceLocation'
    ])
    .find() 
%}
```

Besides that - if you don't execute your `$users` query Craft might fetch the results again and again in certain circumstances so you don't have an array of elements but a query that is fired every single time

In the end I would highly suggest to not loop each user again and again, instead fetch the number of related users for each category via custom Query.
You can just `count` `relations.targetId` from the relations table where the sourceIds are your category ids and loop the result within PHP. I could show it for Craft 3 but I didn't use Craft 2 syntax for over a year

Comment: I tried Eager loading but then the last filter doesn't work in PHP (did in Twig). I use Last because Locations can be nested, and so first pulls only the top level of location, and not the one I care about (the last).

I don't follow what you're saying about relations - that approach, when I tried, was awful for performance? It ran a huge relational DB query 791 times?

Comment: It was my understanding that the way I have it here, I run two DB queries (one to get all users, one to get all locations) and everything else is just PHP looping through those results. When I did nested DB query... it was worse than what I have here.

Comment: Well not exactly `craft.categories.group('locations').limit(null)` will return a query, not an array of users. Craft will cache it internally but as soon as you loop over this query it is executed. That's why I said you should consider to use `eager-loading` Furthermore I didn't mean to create full queries via Craft. I mean to create custom queries on Yii/DB level in order to not fetch them every single time you loop over them. Of course the `last` function (why filter?) won't work since the query is already executed

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I had it in my head that what I was getting back was essentially just a couple of hashes I could loop over, but it seems to be some sort of Craft object with associated overheads.

I need to learn about the Craft DB and Custom Queries I think. Two areas I know nothing about.